# How to publish only what I want, using ROS usb_cam package

Tags: ros

I'm using ROS Kinetic(Ubuntu 16.04)

when I use ROS usb_cam package, it publish many topic

this is list of topic

/usb_cam/camera_info

/usb_cam/image_raw

/usb_cam/image_raw/compressed

/usb_cam/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions

/usb_cam/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates

/usb_cam/image_raw/compressedDepth

/usb_cam/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions

/usb_cam/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates

/usb_cam/image_raw/theora

/usb_cam/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions

/usb_cam/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates

but I want publish only **/usb_cam/image_raw**
How can I do this?

Comment: This is a standard package that tries to satisfy a generic end-user that needs all or a few of them. I imagine that you either ignore them and use only the one that you need or customize it by yourself and remove the unwanted functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The `usb_cam` package is a pre-defined package that publishes everything needed to use a USB camera with ROS. It, like other pre-defined ROS packages, exists for your convenience so that ROS developers can make use of existing solutions.

If you want to change the behavior of a pre-built package, you can find some information here: https://answers.ros.org/question/56885/modify-source-code-of-a-pre-built-packageexternal/